# How can I perform Search&Replace on an XML file after WIX installation?

Tags: string, installation, wix, wix3.5

After installing my files using WIX 3.5 I would like to changes some values in one of my xml files.

Currently there are multiple entries like this:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/XYZ" .../>
```

I would like to change the localhost to the real servername wich is available due to a property. How can I perform this replacement **on each entry** inside this xml file? Is there a way to do this without writing an own CA?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML configuration file is not large, you can load the file into memory and perform replace using JScript.

```
var s = "<endpoint address=\"net.tcp://localhost/XYZ\" .../>";

var re = /"net.tcp:\/\/localhost\//g;
var r = s.replace(re, "\"http://newhost.com/");
```

Here `s` is your complete XML file, `re` is the regular expression, and `r` would contain the result or replace.

You can read and write to public properties of Windows Installer using JScript. Yet there's still one problem: you have to read your XML file and to write it back to disk. To do it, you can use `Win32_ReadFile` and `Win32_WriteFile` custom actions from the [AppSecInc. MSI Extensions](http://code.dblock.org/Source/msiext/1.2/Docs/) library referenced by Yan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456776/how-can-i-perform-searchreplace-on-an-xml-file-after-wix-installation/5456995#5456995).

---

However, it could be easier to write a complete Custom Action which will load your XML configuration file, do the replace, and write the file back to disk. To do it you can use XSLT and JScript (see [an example code](http://www.xmlfiles.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)).

Comment: Actually this is the way I did it yesterday, although I did not use JScript. I simply wrote an C# CustomAction which reads my XML file in deferred mode and performs a simple string replace of "localhost" to my servername property. Yan's idea was good too, but I don't want to save all endpoint adresses in my .wxs file. There will be more endpoints time after time and by using this CA way I don't have to care about it. That's why this answer's got the point! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

[XmlConfig](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlconfig.htm) and/or [XmlFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm) elements are your friends here.

**UPDATE**: Well, according to the comments below, it turns out that only part of the attribute (or element) value should be changed. This seems not to be supported by either of two referenced elements.

I would take one of the two approaches then:

- Use third-party "read XML" actions, like [this one](http://code.dblock.org/Source/msiext/1.2/Docs/)

It's better than creating your own because you can rely on deeper testing in this case

- Teach your build script to control the string pattern

Let's say you put `net.tcp://localhost/XYZ` to build file and your code is pointed out to take this value as a string pattern to use at install time. For instance, keep the string pattern as a Property in your MSI package. When it changes, e.g. to `net.tcp://localhost/ABC` you'll have to change nothing in your action. In this case from a XMLFile perspective you always know your FROM and TO attribute values.

Comment: I'm able to change a whole value by using XmlFile, but in my case I need to change only a substring of the value. That's the problem. How can I do this? I've heard that XPath may be the solution, but I don't know how to implement an XPath Substring expression into my WIX code...

Comment: I'm more confused then before :) I don't understand how I could use the third-party app to really do what I want. Hm... So you mean that I should create properties for each endpoint adress like the one I provided in my example, so that I only need to change the properties? It would work, of course, but That would mean to update the setup each time a new endpoint has to be added.

Comment: InstallShield has XML Read/Write and WiX only has XML Write. Either way there are no RegEx functions built into MSI so you'll be needing a custom action of some sort even if WiX had XML Read and Write because you need to be able to transform your data in between

Comment: @Markus No, you don't need to create a property for each endpoint. Yan suggests to store the substring that needs to be updated as a property in your setup (rather than hardcoding it in Custom Action). It would be `FROM`. After setup you will know `TO`, and apply `replace(FROM, TO)`.

Then if the substring changes, all you will have to update would be the `FROM` property in your installation package.

Comment: @Alexey But the question is how to perform replace(FROM, TO) on my xml file. I'm not creating the file during installation (if I would, I would not have any problems ;) ), the file is only copied to the program directory. AFTER copying it, it has to be updated with the correct server name in each endpoint entry (there are about 7 entries). So the problem is just how to manipulate the file after installation. An C# CA would be a simple way, but I would like to do it without CA... But it seems to me, that there is no way atm. Or I'm still missing the point ;)

Comment: @Markus: It seems Alexey has got my idea correctly. So, the point is the actual replace goes in a property, not in XML. Let's say you have an MSI property ENDPOINTADDRESS, which holds `net.tcp://localhost/XYZ` when you build your package. In immediate CA when you know true server name, you change the value of ENDPOINTADDRESS. And you have `<XmlFile ... Value="[ENDPOINTADDRESS]" />`. So, basically you have only 1 immediate CA and let the XmlExtension to its job. Hope this clarifies things a bit

Comment: And of course, you'll have to have XmlFile entries for each of the places in config you'd like to change. That means if you hoped for a single statement to take general XPath and replace FROM with TO throughout your XML file, then I have to disappoint you :) - you should white a totally custom thing for this

Comment: @Yan I guess I got your idea wrong from the first time. Now I understand better what you propose, however, not completely as I haven't used WiX XmlExtensions.

Comment: Bob Arnson has explained the general idea in his Semi-Custom Action article: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/07/01/semi-custom-actions/

Comment: Yan: Your idea is good and I could do it this way but I have decided to write a simple CA to do the job since it's easier then performing the XML changes and I don't have to care about new endpoints, which in your way have to be inserted into my .wxs file. Upvote for your answer, but point to Alexey since his way is more practicable for me.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield has a built-in data driven custom action called Text Search.  It basically allows for RegEx style replacements like what you are describing.

WiX doesn't have this functionality but you could write a custom action ( say using C#/DTF ) to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There nothing in Wix, you can do to change something in a file without using a custom action. If you don't want to use CA, you can consider saving the settings in some other place e.g. User's registry and always read that setting from there